# Цикл в переменную

Tags: php, laravel

Как сделать из цикла переменную?

```
$prices = Price::where('product_id','=',$id)->get(); // Получаем массив с ценами в магазинах
foreach($prices as $row) {
    $store_data = Store::where('id','=',$row->store_id)->get();
    foreach($store_data as $store) {
        echo '
            <tr>
                <td><a href="/store/'.$store->id.'">'.$store->title.'</a></td>
                <td>'.$store->address.'</td>
                <td>'.$row->price.'</td>
                <td>'.$row->updated_at.'</td>
            </tr>
        ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Какой результат ожидается? Что в итоге должно оказаться в переменной? Таблица?

Comment: В итоге в переменной должно оказаться экранирование, тобишь <tr>

Comment: Если правильно понял, то может быть цикл вынести в функцию? Соответственно она будет возвращать необходимый результат

Comment: меня смущает количество запросов которые могут у вас получится в цикле, может стоит сначала получить все id потом используя в запросе in выбрать их 1 раз ` DB::table('store')
                    ->whereIn('id', array(1, 2, 3))->get();` и уже циклом проходится. p.s. просто предложение. если уточните что нужно в итоге получить попробую вам помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должна быть настроена связь Price - Store.

```
$tbody = '';
foreach(Price::with('store')->where('product_id', $id)->get() as $price) { // with() подгружает связанные сущности Store
    $tbody .= '
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/store/' . $price->store->id . '">'  .$price->store->title . '</a> </td>
            <td>' . $price->store->address . '</td>
            <td>' . $price->price . '</td>
            <td>' . $price->updated_at . '</td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
```

Результат будет в `$tbody`.

Если делать все по-хорошему, то из контроллера вам нужно передавать
`$prices = Price::with('store')->where('product_id', $id)->get()`
и затем в шаблоне

```
@foreach($prices as $price)
    <tr><a href="/store/{!! $price->store->id !!}">{!! $price->store->title !!}</a> </td>
        <td>{!! $price->store->address !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $price->price !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $price->updated_at !!}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

И ссылку конечно лучше заменить на route или action.